# How to add a column in .Net Identity ApplicationUser model to point to a foreign model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, identity

I am trying to use Asp.Net MVC framework with the built in Identity system that is provided by Microsoft out-of-the-box.

However, I need to capture more data about the user.

To minimize the changes to the Identity classes, I need created a new model called "User" where I put in all of my custom attributes. Then I added an attribute called "SystemId" which is a foreign key to the `ApplicationUser` model.

Here is what I have done

Here is my custom `User` model

```
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public string SystemId { get; set; }


    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Index("IX_Username", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Role")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public int CurrentClientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Campaign")]
    public int? CurrentCampaignId { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    public virtual Campaign Campaign { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public virtual List<UserToPrivilege> UserToPrivileges { get; set; } 

    public User()
    {
        DateTime UtcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

        Status = "active";

        MiddleName = null;

        UserToPrivileges = new List<UserToPrivilege>();

        CreatedAt = UtcNow;

        LastUpdatedAt = UtcNow;
    }

}
```

Then in the `IdentityModel` class I changed my `ApplicationUser` class to the following

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

but when I try to create my migration like so

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Force
```

I get the following error

> The property 'Id' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The
>   property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a
>   non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type
>   must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type.

What am I doing wrong? How can I link custom `User` model to the `ApplicationUser` model in belong to relation?

Comment: Why didn't you just inherit ApplicationUser in the User class?

Comment: That sound like a good idea. when I do that then will I have one model or two? from a data view will I then have one table instead of two?

Comment: Should only be one, but I can't remember I haven't done that in a couple years.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change class name. Then try to add `public virtual ApplicationUser` to  your new class hope this works,  because worked for me.
I used new class `UserProfile` it looks like this:

```
[Table("UserProfiles")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Gender { get; set; }

    public string UrlSeo { get; set; }
}
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: What class name that I should change?

Comment: You're using class name User, so if Identity system generates same name so try change it and it will work, I worked with this problem too,  changed class name to UserProfile or other and it is working now.